# Why dont the divs appear inline-block in a html section?

Tags: css, html

So I am using a Html5 template. It is a onepager and I want a section with 'business hours' , with like three days - with their corresponding times- on each line. So I want a line with de divs mon-tue-wed, another beneath it with thu-fri-sat and below sunday.

I have divs like this:

```
<div>
<strong> Monday </strong><br>
09.15 - 10.00 .. <br>
11.15 - 12:00 ..<br>    
17:30 - 18:15 .. <br>
19:15- 20:00 ..
</div>
<br>
```

etc.

All divs are children of :

```
<section id="schedule" class="times">
```

but whenever I refer to it in CSS using this:

```
        section.times> div {
            background-color: #e8edec;
            display: inline-block;

        }
```

Why does it still display everything underneath eachother?

Comment: because you have a `<br>` tag under each div

Comment: @Cfreak That did the trick indeed! Didnt know that was the culprit. Now every div is lined up correctly, however, the headers (the name of the days) are not aligned in a straight line because of its different sizes of content. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I guess that this kind of data is better displayed inside a table...

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps, delete the `<bar>`..
made css code for you.
Html:

```
<div class="c1">
<strong> Monday </strong><br>
09.15 - 10.00 .. <br>
11.15 - 12:00 ..<br>    
17:30 - 18:15 .. <br>
19:15- 20:00 ..
</div>


<div class="c2">
<strong> Monday </strong><br>
09.15 - 10.00 .. <br>
11.15 - 12:00 ..<br>    
17:30 - 18:15 .. <br>
19:15- 20:00 ..
</div>
<br>
</section>
```

Css code:

```
.times> .c1 {
float: left;
width: 33.33333%;}
.times> .c2{
float: left;
width: 33.33333%;}
```

Comment: It will show the days and opening time near each other in same line.